# Expecting an IndexError, but not getting one

Tags: python

For the following exercise I am expecting an IndexError for certain test inputs, but it is not occurring.

**Goal: Write a function that takes in a list of integers and returns True if it contains 007 in order**

**My Function:**

```
def spy_game(nums):
    for x in range(len(nums)):
        print(x)
        try:
            if nums[x]==0 and nums[x+1]==0 and nums[x+2]==7:
                return(True)
        except IndexError:
            return(False)
```

**Test Cases:**

```
#Case 1
    spy_game([1,2,4,0,0,7,5])
#Case 2
    spy_game([1,0,2,4,0,5,7])
#Case 3
    spy_game([1,7,2,0,4,5,0])
```

**Question:**
I included the print statement in the function to try to understand the issue. Case 1 prints `0 1 2 3` and returns `True` which is expected. Case 2 prints `0 1 2 3 4 5 6` and does not return anything. Case 3 prints `0 1 2 3 4 5 6` and returns `False`. For both Case 2 and 3 I would expect it to print up to 5 and at that point result in an IndexError. I am not sure why Case 2 reaches 6 and has no IndexError and why Case 3 reaches 6 and does have one. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is not giving you an IndexError comes from how `and` operations occur in the code. Case 2 will not get to the point of looking for x+2 because it fails on the other operations before.

```
a = [True, True, True]
if a[0] == False and a[100000] == None:
```

for example, will never give you an IndexError because it fails on the first if.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense and I have linked this question to another about short-circuiting. Thanks so much!